# Interaction between minted and beamerswitch

Tags: minted, beamerswitch

The `beamerswitch` package allows to have multiple parallel compilations for the same document, typically to generate both an article and slides version. I wish to use it in conjunction with `minted`, to have slides (and text) with some source code. However, it seems like both package play with auxiliary files in an incompatible way. Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[
  article,
  alsobeamer,
]{beamerswitch}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Test}

\begin{minted}{OCaml}
  type 'a tree = 
    | Leaf 
    | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
\end{minted}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The main compilation succeeds as expected, and produces an article version with the correct minted-highlighted text. However, the secondary compilation fails. As far as I can understand from the log, the relevant error is

```
! Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted was
probably given a file that does not exist--otherwise, you may need 
the outputdir package option, or may be using an incompatible build tool,
or may be using frozencache with a missing file.
```

I tried setting explicitly `minted`'s cache directory with `\usepackage[cachedir=_minted-mwe]{minted}`, but that did not seem to help. There is probably something smarter of a similar flavour to be done, but I could not figure out what.

Comment: Btw, the question would probably deserve the `beamerswitch` tag, but I am not privileged enough to create it.

Comment: I have no problems compiling your example. Did you install [pygments](https://pygments.org) and did you use `-shell-escape`?

Comment: Are both jobs successful? It is expected that the main job is successful. The one failing is the job spawned by `alsobeamer`, supposed to generate `mwe-slides.pdf` (if the main file is called `mwe.tex`).

Comment: Ha, you are right, there is something fishy there: I am using codium with the LatexWorkshop extension, which provides a recipe system for building. I though the recipe I was using was equivalent to the command `xelatex -shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error mwe.tex`, but apparently using this directly has a different effect: the compilation does not error, but the output slide is blank (the code printed by minted is missing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `beamerswitch` documentation has an example on page 6 on how to enable shell-escape for spawned processes:

```
\newcommand*{\SpawnedCompiler}{latexmk -silent -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode}
\documentclass[
  article,
  alsobeamer,
]{beamerswitch}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Test}

\begin{minted}{OCaml}
  type 'a tree = 
    | Leaf 
    | Node of 'a * 'a tree * 'a tree
\end{minted}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: My bad for not reading the manual carefully enough, thank you!

Comment: @MevenLennon-Bertrand You're welcome!